# declaring long[] array in java

Tags: java, arrays, long-integer

Can anyone tell me why cant i declare array like this?

```
long[] powers = { 0, 0, 1, 7, 35, 155, 651, 2667, 10795, 43435,
                174251, 698027, 2794155, 11180715, 44731051, 178940587,
                715795115, 2863245995, 11453115051, 45812722347, 183251413675,
                733006703275, 2932028910251, 11728119835307, 46912487729835,
                187649967696555, 750599904340651, 3002399684471467};
```

Compiler says that the literal of type int is out of range. I also tried to to cast it to long like this

```
long[] powers = { 0, 0, 1, 7, 35, 155, 651, 2667, 10795, 43435,
                174251, 698027, 2794155, 11180715, 44731051, 178940587,
                715795115, (long)2863245995, (long)11453115051, (long)45812722347, etc ...
```

but nothing changed also tried someting like this `Long.valueOf(x)` where x is number whitch compiler has problem with.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: append a L to your numbers. I.e : 2863245995L and so on.

Comment: The key principle is that the type and value of a Java expression is independent of how it is being used. 11453115051 is an over-large int literal regardless of subsequent casting or being in a long[] initializer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Plain number is considered as `int` in java. Append `L` which are bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to convert `long`.

```
long[] powers = {..., 2863245995L, 11453115051L, ...};
```

According to [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type `int`.
>
> The suffix L is preferred, because the letter l (ell) is often hard to
>   distinguish from the digit 1 (one).

Comment: @Yetti You seems to be new here. Don't forget to accept the answer if it has helped you and solved your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried something like this?

```
long[] powers = { 0, 0, 1, 7, 35, 155, 651, 2667, 10795, 43435,
            174251, 698027, 2794155, 11180715, 44731051, 178940587,
            715795115L, 2863245995L, 11453115051L, 45812722347L, 183251413675L,
            733006703275L, 2932028910251L, 11728119835307L, 46912487729835L,
            187649967696555L, 750599904340651L, 3002399684471467L};
```